# How to go to the what I want controller when application didFinishLaunching

Tags: ios, swift

When I launching my application, I want go to the custom `view controller`, but the default first `controller` in `storyboard`:

I want go to brown `vc` when launch my `app`:

[image]

My method is below, but get a black screen with `Unable to capture view hierarchy`

1） In `Info.plist`, delete the `Main storyboard file base name` line.

2） In my `Appdelegate.swift`:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    let sb:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let nav: CustomNavController = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CustomNavController") as! CustomNavController

    let red_vc:ViewController = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController

    let green_vc:ViewController2 = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController2") as! ViewController2

    let brown_vc:ViewController3 = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController3") as! ViewController3


    nav.viewControllers = [red_vc, green_vc, brown_vc]

    self.window? = UIWindow.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    self.window?.rootViewController = nav

    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

Result get a black `screen`:

> [image: the result]

Is which step I mistake? and how can I get it well ? When launch my application I want go to brown `vc`.

---

**ATTEMPT - 1**

Using `push` to `brown vc`, it is not work too:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    let sb:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let nav: CustomNavController = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CustomNavController") as! CustomNavController

    let red_vc:ViewController = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController

    let green_vc:ViewController2 = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController2") as! ViewController2

    let brown_vc:ViewController3 = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController3") as! ViewController3

    //nav.viewControllers = [red_vc, green_vc, brown_vc]

    nav.pushViewController(red_vc, animated: false)

    nav.pushViewController(green_vc, animated: false)

    nav.pushViewController(brown_vc, animated: false)

    self.window? = UIWindow.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    self.window?.rootViewController = nav

    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

Comment: You don't need to initialise like above, iOS by default handle this. On viewWillAppear: of Red, use push to move to the brown viewController.

Comment: @aircraft pls check my answer, if necessary i will add the sample project..

Comment: in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions you must have to push a single viewconroller not a multiple viewcontroller your application show all time black screen . hope you are clear with my this explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You no need delete Main storyboard file base name in Info.plist

In AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let brownVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "brownVCIdentifier") as! BrownViewController
        let navigationController = application.windows[0].rootViewController as! UINavigationController
        navigationController.isNavigationBarHidden = true
        navigationController.pushViewController(brownVC, animated: false)
        return true
    }
```

(or)

In RedViewController(first viewController):

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        let brownVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "brownVCIdentifier") as! BrownViewController
        navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden  = true
        navigationController?.pushViewController(brownVC, animated: false)

    }
```

### Github link:

https://github.com/k-sathireddy/DirectNavigationSample

Comment: did you delete `Main storyboard file base name` in `Info.plist`?

Comment: I couldn't understand above comment.. Please specify clearly..Shall i add sample code?

Comment: if it is convenient, you can post your sample code. the `Main storyboard file base name` in `Info.plist` is initial storyboard, app launch will go to the `storyboard` to find the initial `vc`.

Comment: I test your answer , it works for non-delete `Main storyboard file base name` in `Info.plist`, you can add the delete `Main storyboard file base name` in `Info.plist` answer here, then I upvote and close the thread.

Comment: @aircraft why would you want to delete the storyboard in Info.plist? Are you changing your initial view controller dynamically?

Comment: @Sathi Reddy , Could you edit your answer by adding `You no need delete Main storyboard file base name in Info.plist` this sentence in front of your answer? and this could be more  conform to to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the root viewcontroller as `nav` which has no UIView and it's creating a blank view due to which you see the black view when app is launched.

this code `nav.viewControllers = [red_vc, green_vc, brown_vc]` is not making any sense as you cannot set view controllers like this for UINavigationController. Navigation controller works with PUSH/POP mechanism hence you need to push the view controllers on `nav` controller which will correctly setup the view hierarchy. Push the controllers to brown_vc in `nav` and it should work.

Comment: Sorry but this answer is largely incorrect. It is perfectly fine to set the `viewControllers` property of `UINavigationController`. Please read the documentation for the `UINavigationController setViewControllers(_:animated:)` method.

Comment: @Gurdev Singh I use your method to push to `brown vc`, it looks not work for the issue.